# How to loop a statement in C++

Tags: c++

**EDIT :**

Here is the code that works, although if you enter anything but a number, the program goes into an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age; // Declare age as integer

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Age: "; // Asks the user to enter their age
        cin >> age; // Takes input as age
        if (age < 18) // If age is less than 18
            cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl;
    } while (age < 18);
    cout << "Welcome";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**ORIGINAL POST :**

I've recently started learning C++ and would like to know the **best** way to loop the `Enter Age` procedure so that the user is able to re-enter their age.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age; // Declare age as integer

    cout << "Enter Age: "; // Asks the user to enter their age
    cin >> age; // Takes input as age

    if (age < 18) // If age is less than 18
    { 
        cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl;   
    } 

    else if (age >= 18) // If age is greater than 18
    {
        cout << "Welcome" << endl; 
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *most efficient* ?  You're surely not trying to shave nanoseconds off a loop with a human in it ?

Comment: "best" - depends on what you mean 'best' to be; "most efficient" - you should measure each one in perticular case.

Comment: @EdChum Thanks. No, I just wanted to know what would be most efficient so that I can use it within future, much larger programs.

Comment: @CypherPsyco You'd have to profile some specific code for such specific scenario's, but if you're just learning you really shouldn't at all care about efficiency, as in most cases the gains will be ridiculously minor and far outweighed by any gains you could make in readability/maintainability/ease to write.

Comment: You comment is wrong.  The expression `(age >= 18)`, is checking if age is greater than *or equal to* 18.  By the way, the 2nd if is not necessary because the `else` clause means greater than or equal to (in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Efficient can mean many things, but it certainly doesn't mean performance when you write to console (which is expensive enough in terms of performance) and then write for the user to type something (which is many orders of magnitude more expensive in terms of performance).

So let's assume efficiency means ease of typing, ease of reading and ease of maintaining.

```
do
{
    cout << "Enter Age: "; // Asks the user to enter their age
    cin >> age; // Takes input as age
    if (age < 18) // If age is less than 18
        cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl;   
}
while (age < 18);
cout << "Welcome"
```

If you want something that is not as easy to type, read and maintain, I suggest recursion. The (only?) upside of this approach it that it will impress a first semester programming teacher:

```
int GetAge()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Enter Age: "; // Asks the user to enter their age
    cin >> age; // Takes input as age
    if (age >= 18)
        return age;
    cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl;
    return GetAge();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. So console applications where the user is expected to input data is bad? Why is this so?

Comment: Try entering "a".

Comment: @CypherPsyco What do you mean by "bad"? If the goal is to interact with a human, no, it isn't "bad"

Comment: @Caleth Referring to Peter _and then write for the user to type something (which is many orders of magnitude worse)_

Comment: @CypherPsyco He means there is no point to optimising for nanoseconds when it takes a human about a second to read the prompt and press a button.

Comment: @CypherPsyco what we are trying to get you to understand is that you **should not care** about shaving nanoseconds off a round trip through a human, because humans are *billions* of times slower than computers for this sort of task

Comment: @Caleth Ahh, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

actually entering age doesn't need any special algorithm since it isn't a complex process.
simply write:

```
while (age < 18){
cout << "you can't use this program" << endl;
cin >> age;
}
```

(i didn't know where you want to use the loop, so i write this code as an example)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there is no one specific *best* way to do your loop, because you cannot have one loop that trumps all others in efficience and performance and size, etc... . You need to pick a specific parameter by which you want to gauge the "best" loop.

Having said that, an alternate way is to use recursion; this will not need any `while` loop. Since there is no specification as to "which" kind of loop you *have* to use, here is a different alternative to the while loop or the do-while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Age(void)
{
    int age;

    cout << "Enter Age: ";
    cin >> age;

    if (age < 18)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl;
        age = Age(); // recursion here when invalid age is entered
    }

    else if (age >= 18) 
        cout << "Welcome" << endl; 

    return age;
}

int main()
{
    int age = Age();
    cout << age << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I have done here is move the code into a separate function called `Age()`, and call that function in `int main()`. However, I also call the function when the user enters an age smaller than 18, creating a loop where the function is repeatedly called to re-enter the age until an acceptable value is entered. That value is stored in age, which is then returned to the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

A better code, also you have to keep "17 and less than" so it's always less than 18.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int age; 
    cout << "Enter Age: "; 
    cin >> age; 
    if (age <= 17) {
        cout << "Sorry, you cannot use this program" << endl; }
    else {
        cout << "Welcome" << endl; }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```